# (0 , _reactNavigation.createSwitchNavigator) is not a function Evaluating App.js Loading App.js

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having trouble creating Switch Navigator in React Native.

This is the App.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TabNavigator from './Navigation/TabNavigator';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Loading from './Screens/Loading';
import Login from './Screens/Login';
import Home from './Screens/Home';

const Switch = createSwitchNavigator({
  LoginScreen: Login,
  LoadingScreen: Loading,
  HomeScreen: Home
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(Switch);

export default function App() {
  return <AppNavigator />;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what version of react-navigation are u using? pls show your package.json

Comment: "react-navigation": "3.9.4"

Comment: @Gokul Kulkarni  Got any answer?

Comment: In latest versions they have removed switch navigator, I recommend try using stack navigator in most cases it will be helpful. For auth flow check this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the answer

```
"react-navigation" : "4.2.0"
```

So the most compatible version of *react-navigation* is **4.2.0**.